# 15.10 freezes every 10 minutes

Tags: freeze, gnome-session, tracker

Every freeze is preceeded typically by the following *sylsog* entry. It is a gst_discoverer_discover call (one of several hundred recorded immediately before every freeze) as an example:

```
Oct 20 19:35:54 david-1510 gnome-session[1552]: (tracker-extract:1803): Tracker-WARNING **: Call to gst_discoverer_discover_uri(file:///home/david/Downloads/**linux-rpi-4.1.y**/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/hifiberry-dacplus-overlay.dts) failed: Ressource nicht gefunden.
```

(last few words translate to `Resource not found` in English)

Some of the calls are mystifying, like the call to `linux-rpi-4.1.y`. This was part of a firmware package for my Raspberry Pi a couple of days ago that I had downloaded on my Ubuntu 15.10 system and SCP'ed over the LAN to my Raspberry.

I would appreciate any help with the following:

1. What is doing the calling?
2. How has Raspberry Pi firmware "contaminated" my Ubuntu system?
3. How can I recover?

Comment: Please note that 15.10 is not supported here on AskUbuntu.com yet until it will be officially released in a few days.

Comment: Now 15.10 is on-topic, since officially released :)

Comment: my freezes are still happening every 10-15 minutes under 15.10, unless I do not move the mouse while using a browser (had fails under Chrome and Firefix, so not browser-specific).  I have collected the /var/log/syslog entries prior to over 10 freezes & the only thing remotely common is "vector smash protection enabled" - example below

Comment: Nov  2 17:10:23 david-1510 firefox.desktop[1979]: Vector smash protection is enabled.

Comment: had 4 freezes under 15.10 so far today and have stored the snippets of syslog. Nearly all had messages on "Vector smash" of (mainly Chrome, but also Firefox) and "Chrome pepperflash sandboxed".

Comment: In all cases, I was moving the mouse when the freeze happened - don't move the mouse, the system stays up for hours OK.

Comment: Nov  6 12:16:42 david-1510 thunderbird.desktop[2840]: 1446808602549#011addons.update-checker#011WARN#011Update manifest for thunderbird-hotfix@mozilla.org did not contain an updates property
Nov  6 12:16:57 david-1510 google-chrome.desktop[2255]: [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
_italic_Nov  6 12:17:01 david-1510 CRON[3041]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  6 12:17:01 david-1510 google-chrome.desktop[2255]: [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_url_request_info.cpp(219)] Missing colon in HTTP header line "#015".

Comment: I have no freezes with 4.2.0.16.18 kernel, but with later I have them - every 10 minutes